# How to make dataframe from data stored in the link in pyspark?

Tags: scala, pyspark, databricks

Static Data is stored on the provided link:
https://assets.datacamp.com/production/course_4452/datasets/airports.csv

I have used urllib to get data in string format,then converted that data into rdd  also i have used toDF(),to make new dataframe but i am unable to make correct dataframe from the data.

Comment: Show us the code you tries and error you got.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:-

```
import pandas as pd
airportdata = pd.read_csv("https://assets.datacamp.com/production/course_4452
               /datasets/airports.csv")
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(airportdata)
df.take(5)
```

Comment: Actally panadas dataframe cant be stored on multiple clusters so this would be wrong way to do that..

Comment: Your data source (the csv file) itself is stored as a non-distributed CSV file. You'll either store the file itself as a distributed file (in HDFS, Hive or Cassendra for example) or you'll need to read it in as a single unified dataset and then store it on a distibuted storage system.